# SignalR connection handling on app pool recycle

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using SignalR (0.5.3) Hubs for a chat app where each keystroke is sent to the server (saved in the DB), relayed to all clients and a return value (a string token of sorts) is sent back from the server.

It works fine, until the app pool recycles, then it stops relaying the keystrokes to all the clients (because the in-memory server state is lost I suppose) and the server doesn't return back any values as well. At this point, I suppose all requests via SignalR are queued by IIS and then processed once the app pool has been recycled.

My question is how can I handle this scenario so that all clients are aware of the server unavailability/delay due to app pool recycle, notify the user to wait for a while and then resume operation on reconnect?

Answer (score 5):

There's two options.

For 0.5.3 you can detect when the client goes into "reconnecting" or is "disconnected" and notify the user that there is server issues.  Keep in mind in most situations the client will not actually know that it is disconnected if the server just goes away.

OR

If you wait for the next release (1.0alpha) we will take care of the bulk of this for you. On lack of a server we will trigger an onConnectionSlow event which will then result in the client shifting into the "reconnect" (if it does not receive any info) state until the server comes back online.  The client will also know if the server goes away (we're adding this functionality) for edge cases such as an app pool recycle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: On options 1: You are right, the client only gets to know of disconnection after a prolonged delay (timeout), so handling via the reconnection/disconnected events may not work but I'll still give it a shot.

Comment: @Taylor Mullen - Hi, am I right in thinking this means that as of 0.5.3 if signalr server goes away, the client can get stuck trying to reconnect until a timeout, and there are no events on the client side that can be used to detect this at the moment? Cheers Will

Comment: @Will that is partially correct.  In 0.5.3 you will NOT receive any specific event such as "nowReconnecting" but you can detect that SignalR is trying to reconnect via the stateChanged event.  When we go into the reconnecting state the stateChanged event will fire and the new connection state will be reconnecting.  Also, there is no timeout on the client, it will try to reconnect forever.

Comment: @Taylor Mullen - When making the first attempt to reconnect, how soon is the stateChanged event triggered? I'm trying to figure out a way to handle disconnect/reconnect like Gmail does (screenshot http://www.cloudave.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/4f178788af608685466736793d38b555.jpg)

Comment: @Nick in 0.5.3 there are cases when you will never receive a stateChanged event if you've lost the network connectivity.  I'd recommend combating this with pinging the server every X # of seconds and seeing if it fails and determining server availability that way.  However, if you're willing to wait you can wait for the next release of SignalR (1.0alpha) and we'll trigger the stateChanged event the second we realize that the server is gone or the client has lost connectivity.

Comment: @Taylor Mullen - Thanks. I suppose in 1.0a it's through the transport hearbeat functionality? I'll probably put together an interim solution. When is 1.0a due out (approx)?