# How to keep Blazor Server connection active when IIS is recycling the application pool

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor Server intranet application for my customer.  One of the requirements is that they can stay logged in indefinitely.  If they starting inputting some data on a Friday afternoon, they should be able to return on Monday morning and continue working without interruption.

I came to observe that the client-side was getting disconnected from the server about once per day.  When this happened I would see the dreaded Blazor error “Reconnection failed.  Try reloading the page if you’re unable to reconnect.”.  If I click the link to Reload, it immediately reconnects to my server, but any work in process would be lost.

I found the root cause:  by default, IIS is recycling the application pool every 29 hours.  When this happens, the Blazor SignalR connection is getting interrupted, and hence the code running in the browser times out and disconnects.

I am able to work around this issue by disabling application pool recycling altogether.  So far, it looks like that works fine (I could keep connectivity for the past 3 days).  But I am worried this may not be safe long term, since application pool recycling helps deal with issues such as memory leaks, fragmentation, etc.

SO, my question is:  is it possible to configure IIS in way that I can recycle the application pool AND also keep my blazor server connection available during that recycle period?

Comment: You either disable IIS application pool recycle, or accept the fact that connections are reset that way. That's also why Microsoft developed Blazor WebAssembly which won't be interrupted the same way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SignalR connection handling on app pool recycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724819/signalr-connection-handling-on-app-pool-recycle)

Comment: Hi shanabus, thanks for the link.  It does provide some more information, but it doesn't appear to address this problem fully.  When the application pool recycles it appears I am going to lose any application data saved on the server.  Unless perhaps I can save that to disk or my database before recylcing, and then reload it when the new pool is started up.

Comment: If you want to preserve state between refreshes (which is what it seems this really boils down to) I recommend using session storage. When you load a page or component check to see if the appropriate data exists in session storage and initialize your objects and variables from that. You'll have to be sure to clear session storage as needed.

Comment: Hi Lex, actually there are two issues here: 1) I don't want my user's in progress work to get lost during application recycle and 2) I want to preserve some user data.  In my app, I am storing sensitive user data on the server side, and don't want to put that into the browser side session storage.

Comment: Lex, I voted up your original comment, as I could not find any evidence to contradict that statement.  For now, I am just going to disable IIS pool recycling and monitor the stability of my application.

Answer (score 0):

When you recycle an application pool, HTTP.SYS holds onto the client connection in kernel mode while the user mode worker process recycles. After the process recycle, HTTP.SYS transparently routes the new requests to the new worker process. Thus, the client never "loses all connectivity" to the server - the TCP connection is never lost - and never notices the process recycle.

I believe your problem is with the applications running in your application pool that store state within the process, such as whether a user is logged in or not. Everytime the process recycles, that state is automatically lost... which is by-design since that is what a process recycle accomplishes. As a result, your users "lose all connectivity" and "have to log back into their applications" to re-establish that lost state. The only way to fix this is for your applications to store its state outside of the IIS worker process such that it is friendly to being recycled.

The following blog entry talks more about what is going on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/why-do-i-lose-asp-session-state-on-iis6

Comment: Hi Ding, thanks for the suggestions.  In Blazor there is no such concept as a Session.  Blazor uses SignalR protocol, not HTTP.  I have create my own concept of a session and it is true that I lose that data when the application bool recycles.  But in addition to that the browser side displays the error message "Reconnection failed. Try reloading the page if you’re unable to reconnect" because SignalR keeps trying to send data while the server is down.

Comment: For more information about Server disconnection scenarios, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Comment: Ding, thanks for the link.  It is useful information

Comment: Hi Ding, I did upvote your comment because I think it is useful.  But you didn't really answer my question.  Actually Lex Li did seem to provide the most realistic answer to my specific question which is:  what I want to do cannot be done!

Comment: @JasonD Have you found a solution in 2021 ? Still not sure if I should use blazor in my project or not :(

Comment: Hi Adel, the solution for me was to disable Application Pool recycling altogether.  I have sucessfully deployed my customer project and did not see any ill effects from this.  https://serverfault.com/questions/333907/what-should-i-do-to-make-sure-that-iis-does-not-recycle-my-application